# Display InfoWindow only when marker clicked in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, onclick, infowindow, use-state

I want to show infoWindow only when clicked.

I am using useState to update value in order to check if marker is clicked to show InfoWindow else don't show InfoWindow.

my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  GoogleMap,
  useLoadScript,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";
import "./App.css";
import mapStyles from "./mapStyles";

const mapContainerStyle = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100vh",
};
const center = {
  lat: 51.103807,
  lng: 10.057477,
};

const options = {
  styles: mapStyles,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  fullscreenControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
};


export default function App() {
  const [setSState, sstate] = React.useState(null);

  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY,
    libraries,
  });

  if (loadError) return "error loading maps";
  if (!isLoaded) return "loading maps";

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Find a dealer near you</h1>
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
        zoom={6}
        center={{ lat: 50.985509, lng: 10.690508 }}
        options={options}
      >
        <Marker
          position={{ lat: 50.985509, lng: 10.690508 }}
          onClick={() => {
            sstate(center);
            console.log("marker clicked");
          }}
        ></Marker>
        { sstate[0] ?  (
        <InfoWindow
          position={{
            lat: 51.081753,
            lng: 13.696073,
          }}
        >
          <div>
            <h3>Some text</h3>
            <h4>Some text</h4>
            <p>Some text</p>
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
        ): null}
      </GoogleMap>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click the marker InfoWindow doesn't show up. What am I not doing and should do? Is there a different, simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have confused the current state value and a function that lets you update it in the `Marker` handler. You also assign `center` object to state which doesn't have `center[0]` property which you use in your render condition.

Try to replace `const [setSState, sstate] = React.useState(null);` with `const [marker, setMarker] = React.useState(null);` to make things clear.

Change `onClick` in `Marker` to

```
onClick={() => {
  setMarker(center);
  console.log("marker clicked");
}}
```

And place where you render `InfoWindow` to

```
{ marker ? (
  <InfoWindow
    position={{
      lat: 51.081753,
      lng: 13.696073,
    }}
  >
    <div>
      <h3>Some text</h3>
      <h4>Some text</h4>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </InfoWindow>
) : null }
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. I have tried removing the array like you said before, don't know why it works now. I think maybe because I restarted everything since some UI which I changed in code is showing now. Odd..